# Amazon Redshift terminology

Tags: amazon-redshift

What is the proper terminology for Amazon Redshift servers?

Specifically, if I'm querying against Redshift and I don't know or care whether it's a cluster, what do I call it? Is it an *instance*, a *server*, or even a *cluster*? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cluster = externally addressable group of instances, composed of:

  - Node = an instance in the cluster, composed of:

    - Leader Node = accepts connections, plans queries, returns results
    - Compute Node = stores data, executes queries (more or less…)

Comment: So if you wanted to tell someone that you're querying it, what term would you use? Would you use 'cluster'? Is there a more general term that is still accurate?

Comment: I say "Querying the cluster" but I deal with many Redshift clusters. I suspect most would say "Querying the data warehouse".

Comment: Ok, those both seem good. We have test/QA/prod, so that still works. Either "Querying the QA cluster" or "Querying the QA warehouse".

Comment: Most database admins would just say "querying the database" or "querying the production database". We would seldom say "querying the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 cluster" for example unless there is a reason to be very specific. For AWS, I would just say "querying Redshift" if the other side understands AWS otherwise I would say "querying the Redshift database".